# How do you prevent jquery mobile loading dialog?

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile in my phonegap project. For some reason jquery injects a "loading" dialog into the body of my page. I have looked through the documentation but cant seem to find any way to prevent this. My goal is to be able to just turn it off but if there is some css work around I would like to hear it.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you including the standard jquery mobile stylesheet?

Comment: No. Im just using jquery-mobile.js

Comment: Take a look at my answer below and let me know if that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the standard css and the loading dialog will be hidden until you call jQuery.mobile.loading('show') otherwise you can create a custom stylesheet to utilize the same styles that the standard stylesheet uses:

```
/* Loading screen */
.ui-loading .ui-loader {
    display: block;
}
.ui-loader {
    display: none;
    z-index: 9999999;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border:0;
}
```